# Cannot open source file "GL/glew.h"

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2015, glfw, glew

I'm getting into OpenGL and Visual Studio, and just got this warning and couldn't find any possible solution. I've added both GLEW and GLFW Libraries to the `include` directory, and then again in the input section of the Linker menu, in the project's properties. Anyways, Visual Studio seems unable to find any of them.

See these images - they explain it all.

*Include Directories:*

[image]

*Linker Input:*

[image]

*The Problem:*

[image]

*GLEW Directory:*

[image]

*GLFW Directory:*

[image]

[All image link together](http://pastebin.com/XSVLjABK)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your include directories should be pointing to where the header files are, not the **.lib** files.

Change your include directory to go to where the `.h` files are located, for me it's `C:\...\glew-2.0.0\include\GL`

The directories you currently have in it should instead go into `Additional Library Directories` located at **linker->general** in your options

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot man. Just a simple correction, I had to include '...\glew-2.0.0\include' instead of '...\glew-2.0.0\include\GL', but I suppose that's because I specified <GL/glew.h>. Thanks!